# How to use jQuery ajax in Google Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

I have written a code for getting data from another server through JSONP call (based on jQuery) please look at the code below....

```
    $("#submit").click(function() {
var state=$("#state").val();
var city=$("#city").val();
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "http://www.dizainstore.com/chrome/info.php",
             async: true,
             data: "state="+ state+ "&city="+ city,
             dataType: 'jsonp',
              success: function(response) {
                  var centres=response.centres_info.centre;
                  var address=response.centres_info.address;
                  var val ;
                  var val1 ;
                  var und
                  $.each(centres, function(i,cent){
            val += "<div class='box2-l'>" + cent + "</div><div class='box2-r'>" + address[i] + "</div>" ;
                 });
              var new_val = "<div class='box1'><div class='box1-l'>Center List</div><div class='box1-r'>Address List</div>"+val+"</div>"
                  $(".result1").html(new_val);
                               }

         });
         return false;
     });
```

It's working fine for me. but When i used in Google Chrome Extension, it's not working, error occurred :- we can't use jquery Ajax call, they suggest xmlhttprequest. But i dont know how to convert this code into XMLhttpRequest. So please suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the return is JSONP, it appears dizainstore is using a RESTful API and expects you to use JSONP with script injection:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#Script_element_injection

Your code would instead look something like this:

```
function handleDizain(response)
{
    var centres=response.centres_info.centre;
    var address=response.centres_info.address;
    var val ;
    var val1 ;
    var und
    $.each(centres, function(i,cent){
            val += "<div class='box2-l'>" + cent + "</div><div class='box2-r'>" + address[i] + "</div>" ;
    });
    var new_val = "<div class='box1'><div class='box1-l'>Center List</div><div class='box1-r'>Address List</div>"+val+"</div>"
    $(".result1").html(new_val);
}

$("#submit").click(function() {
        var state=$("#state").val();
        var city=$("#city").val();

        //Create a new script tag
        var loader = document.createElement( "script" );
        loader.setAttribute( "type", "text/javascript" );

        //Set the source
        loader.src = "http://www.dizainstore.com/chrome/info.php?state=" + state + "&city=" + city + "&callback=handleDizain";

        //Add it to the body
        document.body.appendChild( loader );

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a cross-origin call in a Chrome extension, you don't have to use JSONP. You can simply use the Chrome extension cross-origin permissions: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

Regards,
Udi